# How to check Rails mail setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, smtp

I am trying to debug how rails sends email.  Currently it doesn't work for me :)

But where in the configurations do I change the SMTP I am trying to send from? And how to I set it up so that on dev/stage/live it uses appropriate SMTP configurations of the server it is mailing from?

Thanks,
Alex

ps - I had originally set it up using this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examples are assuming that you use the mail server MAIL.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM

Action Mailer now uses the Mail gem -- you probably need something like this in your ./config/environments/env.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "MAIL.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'YOUR-DOMAIN.COM',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

see also: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

another way to do this is to put the follwoing into ./config/initializers/setup_mail.rb :

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
      :address              => "MAIL.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM",  
      :port                 => 587,  
      :domain               => "YOUR-DOMAIN.COM",  
     :user_name            => "<username>"
      :password             => "<password>"
      :authentication       => "plain",  
      :enable_starttls_auto => true  
   }
```

e.g. the code above works if you want to use Gmail's SMTP server to send email via your Gmail account..
Other SMTP servers may need other values for :authentication and :enable_starttls_auto 
depending on the SMTP server setup

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot. By the way, should I keep the brackets in '<username>' ?